# JPanel GridLayout make all buttons be in same place

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jbutton

I was created some program for my school that should contains `n*n` buttons.
The buttons should be in Matrix layout with n rows and n cols.

So i created the panel, and I created a class named `Position` that extends `JButton`s - the buttons I want to add to the panel.

I added layout to the panel:

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,n));
```

And then I am creating n*n Positions buttons and adding them to the panel.

The problem is, that all the buttons are adding to the same place (top left of the screen) - even that I can click them in the places they should be! (see screen shot where n is 4)

I can click on the grey area (empty) even the button is not there:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZDnC.png)

**The panel constructor:**

```
    public GamePanel(int n) {
    super();
    this.n = n;
    positions = new Position[n][n];
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(n,n));
    currX = new Random().nextInt(n);
    currY = new Random().nextInt(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Position p = new Position(i, j);
            this.add(p);
            positions[i][j] = p;
        }
    }
```

**The constructor of `Position` class:**

```
public class Position extends JButton {
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean visited = false;

public Position(int x, int y) {
    super("");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
}
```

**The Frame:**

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
private GamePanel gamePanel;
public Game(int n){
    super();
    gamePanel = new GamePanel(n);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(gamePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(new JTextField(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Where can be my mistake?

Comment: Don't post your code as image. it should be as text.

Comment: I wanted to show the program result, ill also write it as text

Comment: A normal `JButton` can be added normally this way. Can you show the code for your constructor of `Position` class?

Comment: Yes, I added the code of position class

Comment: with your provided code parts it is working for me as you want to be. maybe some code in your real implementation cause this mistake.

Comment: So maybe its the frame code? I added it now also

Comment: it is not the frame code :( what you get when you only run the codes you provided

Comment: Your code doesn't have any problem and it works properly as I tested.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: Are you overriding the `getX` and `getY` methods of `JButton` to return your x/y values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after putting your incomplete example back together, I got...

[image: Good output]

Then I noticed the `x`/`y` properties in your `Position` buttons, which made me thing that you've probably included `getX` and `getY` methods, something like...

```
public class Position extends JButton {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean visited = false;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        super("");
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


}
```

Which generated...

[image: Bad ouptut]

So the answer is, include a fully [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

And don't override `getX` and `getY` of the `JButton`, instead, change the methods to something like `getGridX` and `getGridY`